# How do I make sure that there is always something selected in a Spark List?

Tags: list, apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

I have a spark list, which is based on a dataProvider. As the application runs, the data in the dataprovider can change, and also the dataProvider can be swapped for a different one

What I need to do is make sure that something is always selected in the list (unless it is empty)

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to set the property `requireSelection` of your list instance to `true`.

In MXML, it would be:

```
<s:List id="myList" requireSelection="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

After setting its data provider ( or whenever is changed ) you could do a:

```
myList.selectedIndex = 0;
```

, so whenever the is data on your list, its first item will be selected (it could be any index, just remember that it start from 0 to length - 1).